# Edit issue: Couldn't find Client with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, action

I've searched for hours, and I can't seem to find anything that handles my problem here. This might be easy for someone, but it'd be GREATLY appreciated if anyone can help.

I'm creating an app to make a simple CRUD on clients in my database. Index is working fine. And Showing each client with an ID is working great. I see all the details of the client. 
[Image example of index in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCwc8.png)

**But with the edit action I get this error in the browser:**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ClientsController#edit 
Couldn't find Client with 'id'=

Extracted source (around line #30):

29 def edit
30   @client = Client.find(params[:id])
31 end
32
33 def update
```

I don't understand this as I've used the same code in the edit action from the working show action:

```
def show
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
end
```

It appears as if the application is unable to fetch the :id parameter from my browser and place it in the edit form action. The issue might also appear in the update action. I've tried typing in @client = Client.find(1) and it works. It gives me an edit-form with the client_id of 1 in the browser, but of course I want the ID from the browser like how the view action works. So I'm guessing something is wrong with my routing, since the app understands both index and view, but not how to pass on the id to the edit page.

**This is what my route file looks like:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :clients

  match ':controller(/:action(:/id))', :via => [:get, :post]

end
```

**This is what my edit.html.erb looks like**

```
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="clients edit">
<h2>Update client</h2>

<%= form_for(:client, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @client.id}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Client form fields">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Visible</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:visible) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:category_id) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Short description</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:shortdescription) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Long description</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:longdescription) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Phonenumber</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:phonenumber) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:email) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:country) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Lattitude</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:lattitude) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Longtitude</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:longtitude) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Update Client") %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

**This is what my rake routes looks like**

```
     Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
    clients GET      /clients(.:format)                     clients#index
        POST     /clients(.:format)                     clients#create
 new_client GET      /clients/new(.:format)                 clients#new
edit_client GET      /clients/:id/edit(.:format)            clients#edit
 client GET      /clients/:id(.:format)                 clients#show
        PATCH    /clients/:id(.:format)                 clients#update
        PUT      /clients/:id(.:format)                 clients#update
        DELETE   /clients/:id(.:format)                 clients#destroy
   root GET      /                                      clients#index
```

**And this is what my clients_controller.rb looks like**
    `class ClientsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @clients = Client.order("name ASC")
end

def show
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @client = Client.new({:country => 'DK'})
end

def create
    @client = Client.new(client_params)
    if @client.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render('new')
    end
end

def edit
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @client = Client.find(params[:id])
    if @client.update_attributes(client_params)
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @client.id)
    else
        render('edit')
    end
end


def delete
end

private

    def client_params

        params.require(:client).permit(:name, :visible, :category_id, :shortdescription, :longdescription, :phonenumber, :email, :country, :lattitude, :longtitude)
    end
end`
```

**I hope anyone can help! Anything, really, since i'm stuck.** 
I've tried reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html but I cant seem to find out where it all goes wrong.

**EDIT:** It could also be that I'm linking wrongly to the edit-action. Not sure, but here is the index.html.erb

```
<div class="clients index">
<h2>Clients</h2>

<%= link_to("Add New Client", {:action => 'new'}, :class => 'action new') %>

<table class="listing" summary="Clients list">
    <tr class="header">

        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Visible</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <% @clients.each do |client| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= client.id %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= client.name %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= client.category_id %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= client.visible ? 'Yes' : 'No' %></td>
        <td class="actions">
            <%= link_to("Show", {:action => 'show', :id => client.id}, :class => 'action show') %>
            <%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit'}, :class => 'action edit') %>
            <%= link_to("Delete", '#', :class => 'action delete') %>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no `Client` with the given `id`. You can check that if the client exists from your console using `Client.exists?(id_of_the_client_you_are_searching)`

Comment: But id's with my clients do exist? I get them in my view and they are passed into the view form

Comment: What is the url you use to access to your page?

Comment: @Geoffroy I just made an edit to show my index.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing id attribute in your path. Make the following changes please:

```
<%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => client.id}, :class => 'action edit') %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! In hindsight, should've noticed myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `id` to your edit link

```
<%= link_to("Edit", {:action => 'edit', :id => client.id }, :class => 'action edit') %>
```

Comment: Whoa. How simple. It's those small things. Thanks for the effort guys!

Comment: It should be client not @client.

Comment: True! Marked yours as the right answer hence the correct syntax! Thanks to you both though